# how to pass a predicate to algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, c++11, predicate

I'm having a problem passing predicate using lambda, I'm trying to move element that matches the predicate to the beginning of a second container, but it didn't seem to work, so what's wrong please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

    template <typename iterator, typename Container, typename T>
    void move_if(iterator b, iterator e, Container o, T pred)
    {
        if(pred)
        {
            o.insert(o.begin(),pred);
        }

    }


    int main()
    {
        vector<int>v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        vector<int>v2;
        for (auto i=v.begin(); i !=v.end(); ++i)
            save_if(v.begin(), v.end(), v2, []( vector<int>::iterator i){return (*i>5);});

        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the for-loop be part of `move_if` rather than the main program? And what do you mean by `if(pred)`?

Comment: Note that as of C++11 there is a difference between moving and copying an element. As such you shouldn't use the word "move" if you want to copy elements. Googling move-semantics should give quite a lot results to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out, I did some modifications on your code:

```
template <typename iterator, typename Container, typename T>
void move_if(iterator a, iterator b, Container &o, T pred)
{
    for (auto i = a; i != b; i++)
    {
        if (pred(*i))
            o.insert(o.begin(), *i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int>v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    vector<int>v2;

    move_if(v.begin(), v.end(), v2, [](int i) { return !(i > 5); });
}
```

Note: As the comments, It's recommended to rename `move_if` to `copy_if`, if the functionality is as above code, otherwise you should really move items.

Comment: Note that `v2` in main is never modified since you pass a copy.

Comment: It should _at least_ remove the element from the source container, otherwise it's just `copy_if`

Comment: Agree, but I just fixed his problem, the name was not my choice.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    std::vector<int> v2;

    std::vector<int>::const_iterator
        it = std::remove_copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
                                 std::back_inserter(v2),
                                 [](int const& i){return i <= 5;});
    v.erase(it, v.end);

    return 0;

}
```

You can read more about [`remove_copy_if` on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy); it *removes* elements from the input range and copies them to the output unless the predicate returns true.

Note that this is an STL *remove*, so you need to call erase afterwards to shrink the input. The semantics of this solution are slightly different to the code you posted, but more similar to your description of what you wanted.

Comment: Note that remove_copy_if doesn't move but copy its elements.

Comment: @bamboon I've clarified and improved my answer; what do you think?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Perfect that way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no overload of [std::vector::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) that takes a predicate as second argument, so this line is wrong:

```
o.insert(o.begin(),pred);
```

Furthermore, the predicate needs to be called with an argument,

```
pred(someArg);
```

which in your case would be an `std::vector<int>::iterator`. Also, `save_if` is not the same as `move_if`. But more importantly, it isn't clear at all what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, stateless lambdas like `[](){return true}` that do not capture anything can be implicitly converted to function pointers.  When you do `if(pred)` you are converting your stateless lambda into a function pointer, checking if that pointer is non-null (it is non-null).  This is not what you want to do.

Here is an implementation that `move`s things between `b` and `e` that `pred(x)` says should be moved:

```
template <typename iterator, typename Container, typename T>
void move_if(iterator b, iterator e, Container o, T pred)
{
  for( auto i = b; i != e;++i) {
    if(pred) {
      o.insert(o.end(),std::move(*i));
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I inserted at `o.end()`, because the `Container` you want is probably `vector`, and inserting at the `end()` of `vector` is much faster.

In reality, you probably want to take an output iterator (and by default, use `std::back_inserter` from a `Container`) and output your data to that.  Similarly, `remove_move_if` would be a better way to remove, shuffling the elements down the `b`-`e` range, and returning an `iterator`.

Finally, ranged-based algorithms are worth writing.  Instead of taking a begin/end iterator pair, take a single object upon which `begin(c)` and `end(c)` have been overriden to return begin/end.  If you are working on a sub-range, you can pass in a begin/end range of iterators `struct` with begin/end suitably overridden.